# Finding the Value of Ties

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, percentages

**THE CHALLENGE**

If "Winning all the time = 1" "Losing all the time = -1" "Tie all the time = 0"

What value would "Winning HALF the time" be?

Is there an error in my original variables that would help resolve this?

**THE APPLICATION**

I am developing a game that, for simplicity, can be compared to Rock-Paper-Scissors (Roshambo).  Each action (Rock) will always beat another (Scissors), tie against itself (Rock VS Rock) and lose against another (Paper).  However, there are additional actions (Hammer) that when paired against others (Rock) will resolve with a coin-flip (50% chance to win).

I am trying to find the value of each of these actions based on how often they win pairings.  I have assigned guaranteed wins 1, guaranteed losses -1, and ties 0.  I am stumped on what I would assign to a 50% chance to win, which leads me to believe there may be an error in my original variables.

In an effort to keep the post short I omitted the details of the game.  However, if more detail would help I can provide.

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the value of winning half the time depend on what happens the half of the time in which you don't win (i.e. what percentage of that time are you losing and what percentage is it a tie?)?

Comment: This is a good point.  Which means I may need to restate my question entirely.